# Streamreader case sensitivity

Tags: powershell, streamreader

I have recently switched some scripts from using Powershell Get-content to streamreader- everything is now greatly faster however I am having a problem with case sensitivity being in place on searches.

I did see another post on stackoverflow but couldn't work out what to change (Newbie!) so hoping someone can advise.

An example of my script is

```
$fullname = Get-Item c:\file.txt
$sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader("$fullName")
while (($line = $sr.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
if ($line.contains("London")) { "$line" | add-content c:\results.txt}
```

I've read that StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase somewhere in the above might help - Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are using the .NET method contains. It's easy to get what you want. So,

```
$line.contains("London")
```

is case-sensitive but

```
$line -contains "London"
```

is not. This may explain it better:

```
PS C:\> "london".contains("London")
False
PS C:\> "london" -contains "London"
True
```

Example:

```
PS C:\> cat c:\temp\a.txt
Londonnn
london
New York
hello
world

PS C:\> $sr = new-object System.io.streamreader(get-item C:\Temp\a.txt)
PS C:\> while ($line = $sr.readline()) { if ($line -contains "London"){ $line} }
london
```

Update:
-Contain would expect 'exact' word regardless of case. You might want to use -match instead for your use case. See the difference:

```
PS C:\> while ($line = $sr.readline()) { if ($line -match "London"){ $line} }
Londonnn
london
```

Comment: Thanks very much for quick response and explanation but I have tested ($line -contain "London") and it gives me empty output.  The old line if ($line.contains("London")) did produce a lot of matches - any ideas?

Comment: do you have a typo there? -contains, not -contain

Comment: Hi, no typo in the code - sorry I did typo in the comment.

Comment: Thanks again Adil - you code has helped.  It does seem to work ok but with a couple of issues I noticed.  If my file has London or LONDON - it finds these - which is great.  However on my tests if London is written as London: - it will ignore this line because of the : even though London is on the line.  Also if I put in an extra space after the word London it misses this also (unless I add the space in the search like if ($line -contains "London ")

Comment: I see, if the values are like that I would suggest using other operators like '-like "london*', or my favorite '-match'.

Comment: That's perfect - thanks for your patience with me.  You've been a great help!

Comment: Thanks Adil - if it's not too much trouble do you know of a quick way to fetch identical values only once (similar to 'sort-object -unique' in Powershell)?